# Need SQL to generate multiple rows from subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that selects a month and year from a complex heirachy of tables.  To simplify this question, we can use this query:

```
select 2 as month, 2018 as year from dual;
```

I need SQL that will use that query as a subquery to output 3 row:  that month as well as with the preceeding 2 months (including years).  So the output needed for that specific case would be:

```
Month  Year
2      2018
1      2018
12     2017
```

I have no idea how to proceed.  Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the month/year already in a `DATE` column, it would be one less conversion, but if they are separate columns like you have provided, you can use a query like the one below.

#### Query

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 2 AS month, 2018 AS year FROM DUAL)
    SELECT TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (TO_DATE (month || '-' || year, 'MM-YYYY'), ((LEVEL * -1) + 1)), 'MM')
               AS month,
           TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (TO_DATE (month || '-' || year, 'MM-YYYY'), ((LEVEL * -1) + 1)), 'YYYY')
               AS year
      FROM sample_data
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
```

#### Result

```
   MONTH    YEAR
________ _______
02       2018
01       2018
12       2017
```

Answer (score 2):

For Oracle 12+:

```sql
select *
from
  (select 2 as month, 2018 as year 
  from dual) complex_query
 ,lateral(
       select 
         extract(month from add_months(dt, 1-level)) as month,
         extract(year  from add_months(dt, 1-level)) as year
       from (
         select 
           to_date(complex_query.year||'-'||complex_query.month||'-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') as dt
         from dual
       )
       connect by level<=3
  );
```

For previous versions:

```sql
select 
  complex_query.*
 ,extract(year  from (to_date(year||'-'||month,'yyyy-mm')-delta)) year_2
 ,extract(month from (to_date(year||'-'||month,'yyyy-mm')-delta)) month_2
from
  (select 2 as month, 2018 as year 
  from dual) complex_query
 ,(select 
     NUMTOYMINTERVAL(level-1,'month') delta
   from dual
   connect by level<=3
  ) v
```

Results:

```
     MONTH       YEAR     YEAR_2    MONTH_2
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2       2018       2018          1
         2       2018       2017         12
         2       2018       2017         11
```

Answer (score 0):

Would `union` work?

```
with primary_month as (
  select 2 as month, 2018 as year from dual
)
select (case when month = 1 then 13 else month end) - 1 as month , case when month = 1 then year-1 else year end as year from primary_month
union
select month, year from primary_month
union
select month + 1 as month, year from primary_month
;
```

This example won't handle boundary cases like if the primary month is January, since there is no month 0, but I'm not sure if that's what you're going for and it depends on the real query and schema (e.g. are you using timestamp columns?)

Comment: Yes, month `0` is a **K.O.** Check the function [ADD_MONTHS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/ADD_MONTHS.html#GUID-B8C74443-DF32-4B7C-857F-28D557381543)